# Inserting empty value in database

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am generating registration id using GCM, and it is generating value for fine. But my problem is that I am sending data to asp.net server using soap. It is storing empty value in database.

I have tried so much but don't know what the problem. I have also checked by giving fixed value of regID and it stored data that time.

my code is as below : Please give me solution.

```
 private class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getApplicationContext());
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getApplicationContext());

        String regId = GCMRegistrar
                .getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());

        if (regId.equals("")) {
            flag = 1;
            GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), "1507652xxxxx");

        } else {
            Log.v("Registration", "Already registered, regId: " + regId);
        }

        if (flag == 1) {
            regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());

            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            regisid = new PropertyInfo();
            regisid.setName("RegId");
            regisid.setValue(regId);
            regisid.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(regisid);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envp.dotNet = true;
            envp.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envp.getResponse();
                Response = response.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return Response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the webservice call in the onRegistered callback method of GCMIntentService.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}   


@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String regId) {
    //Call webservice here

}
```

Comment: one more question, it is inserting data everytime. so is there anyway by which it inserts data only when it is new registration ?

Comment: I am calling this : GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), "150765212908"); onCreate() of application so everytime, it is registering data.

Comment: you can store a boolean value in SharedPreference when your registration process is successful. Check this value before calling register().

Comment: solved it. i check whether registration id is null then only register else do nothing.